# Tensorflow indicator matrix for top n values

Tags: tensorflow, vectorization

Does anyone know how to extract the top n largest values per row of a rank 2 tensor?

For instance, if I wanted the top 2 values of a tensor of shape [2,4] with values:

[[40, 30, 20, 10], [10, 20, 30, 40]]

The desired condition matrix would look like:
[[True, True, False, False],[False, False, True, True]]

Once I have the condition matrix, I can use tf.select to choose actual values.

Thank you for assistance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it using built-in [tf.nn.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#top_k) function:

```
a = tf.convert_to_tensor([[40, 30, 20, 10], [10, 20, 30, 40]])
b = tf.nn.top_k(a, 2)

print(sess.run(b))
TopKV2(values=array([[40, 30],
   [40, 30]], dtype=int32), indices=array([[0, 1],
   [3, 2]], dtype=int32))

print(sess.run(b).values))
array([[40, 30],
       [40, 30]], dtype=int32)
```

To get boolean `True/False` values, you can first get the k-th value and then use `tf.greater_equal`:

```
kth = tf.reduce_min(b.values)
top2 = tf.greater_equal(a, kth)
print(sess.run(top2))
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Is there an easy way to use those top_k values to obtain a tensor of of the original size with True and False values?

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean tf.greater_equal(a, kth) ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. You can express the thanks by accepting/upvoting the answer :P

Comment: How Do I use this TopK function in C++?

Answer (score 3):

you can also use [`tf.contrib.framework.argsort`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argsort)

```
a = [[40, 30, 20, 10], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
idx = tf.contrib.framework.argsort(a, direction='DESCENDING')  # sorted indices
ranks = tf.contrib.framework.argsort(idx, direction='ASCENDING')  # ranks
b = ranks < 2  
# [[ True  True False False] [False False  True  True]]
```

Moreover, you can replace `2` with a 1d tensor so that each row/column can have different `n` values.