# How to select top-k elements of a keras dense layer?

Tags: python-3.x, keras-layer, max-pooling

I'm trying to perform a `k-max pooling` in order to select `top-k` elements of a dense with shape `(None, 30)`. I tried a `MaxPooling1D` layer but it doesn't work, since keras pooling layers require at least a 2d input shape. I'm using the following `Lambda` layer, but I got the following error:

```
layer_1.shape
(None, 30)
layer_2 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.top_k(x, k=int(int(x.shape[-1])/2),
                                                sorted=True, 
                                                name="Top_k_final"))(layer_1)
```

> Error: File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 474, in **call**
>       output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line
>   652, in compute_output_shape
>       return K.int_shape(x)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 591, in int_shape
>       return tuple(x.get_shape().as_list()) AttributeError: 'TopKV2' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808772/tensorflow-top-n-values-in-tensor), I solved the problem. In fact, I solved the problem by adding `.values` to get the tensor values from the `tf.nn.top_k`, as follows. But I'm not sure if my solution is correct or not.

```
layer_2 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.top_k(x, k=int(int(x.shape[-1])/2),
                                                sorted=True, 
                                                name="Top_k_final").values)(layer_1)
```

Comment: Is there someone who could clarify more?

Comment: If you check here, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k, you will see that ```tf.nn.top_k()``` returns both the values and indices of the top k elements. Hence the ```.values``` specification.